# Physical meaning of Boyer-Lindquist coordinate

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, coordinate-systems, kerr-metric

The Kerr metric in the Boyer-Linquist coordinate is
$$\mathrm{d} s^{2}=  \frac{\Delta}{R^{2}}\left(\mathrm{d} t-a \sin ^{2} \theta\, \mathrm{d} \phi\right)^{2}-\frac{\sin ^{2} \theta}{R^{2}}\left[\left(r^{2}+a^{2}\right) \mathrm{d} \phi-a\,\mathrm{d} t\right]^{2} -\frac{R^{2}}{\Delta} \mathrm{d} r^{2}-R^{2}\,\mathrm{d} \theta^{2} ,$$
where $R^2=r^2+a^2\cos^2 \theta$, and $\Delta=r^2 -2mr +a^2$.

Usually, we give the coordinates some physical meaning; for example, the Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates represent an ongoing or outgoing light ray. My question is, what is the physical meaning of this coordinate? I want to relate it to a radial static observer, the observer is described by $(\partial_t,\partial_r,\partial_{\theta},\partial_{\phi})$ where $\partial_t$ is the 4-velocity of the observer. My consideration is in this coordinate, there is a coordinate singularity at the horizon, therefore it corresponds to an observer static along the radial direction(in ongoing or outgoing coordinates, there is no coordinate singularity).  My question is my argument right or not?

Comment: There is no reason that coordinates in GR need to have any physical meaning.

Comment: @Ghoster Yeah, I know, but sometimes you could explain it physically, right? Like Eddington Finkelstein coordinates, which is related to an ingoing or outgoing light ray. I wonder whether there is something similar for the BL coordinate.